# MIPS: "lw" instruction path

Tags: mips, hardware, processor, mips32

From lecture notes:
[image]

from what I understand, doesn't the black dots indicate the binary bits is being copied to both paths moving forward?

For example, instruction bits `I[20-16]` should be going into the `Read register 2` and `Write register`. It's just that in the end, the `Read data 2` is not being used due to the `MUX` selecting 1.

Did my prof choose not to draw the red lines going to the `Read register 2` path just to emphasize on the most significant path? Or does the black dot before `Read register 2` have the ability to close off irrelevant data path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your professor is only highlighting the paths that affect the result. This is normal -- if every path that contained data were highlighted, *everything* would be red.